# Do I have a Virtual Machine, within another Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, docker, azure

I need to configure a `Linux Virtual Machine` in `Azure` with `GPU`, and `Docker` to run my application. I recently achieved an initial setup by following the steps:

Created the `VM` in `Azure` -> installed the extension for `NVidia` drivers -> installed `Docker` following [this guide](https://medium.com/hardwareandro/install-docker-on-azure-virtual-machine-github-docker-hub-azure-deploy-pipeline-part-1-4b1e73dd0d7).

My `Azure VM` properties are `Standard NC4as T4 v3`, `Linux (ubuntu 20.04) 0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal`, `20_04-lts-gen2`, `V2`.

Currently I understand that `Docker` runs on a `VM`. Does this mean that I now have `Docker` running inside one `VM`, inside another `VM`?

What is the correct way to get what I need?

Comment: Docker uses something called "Containers" which you can think of as small virtual boxes that hold everything a program needs to run but they are different from a VM as they do not virtualize an operating system. If you want to learn more about it this is a good resource: https://www.atlassian.com/microservices/cloud-computing/containers-vs-vms

Comment: What is it that you need?

Comment: I need to understand how Docker is running inside my virtual machine.

Comment: Docker does not virtualize hardware, so its not a VM in the way you are thinking of one (where a hypervisor has raw hardware access, and presents virtual hardware to client VMs). as such the requirement that the hypervisor have dedicated/exclusive access to hardware is not violated.

Comment: It may be helpful to read up on documentation for Docker, particularly the parts explaining what it is and how it works. I'm guessing that would answer these questions you have.

Comment: But, you do end your post with a question mark. My question is: what is your actual question? You describe what you have already done, and then wonder about what is happening, but you do not anywhere state a problem or setup you haven't yet been able to attain.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I understand that Docker runs on a VM. Does this mean that I now have Docker running inside one VM, inside another VM?

Docker doesn't run on a VM. Docker Desktop, does start a tiny Linux VM so that Docker can make use of Linux kernnel's cgroups & namespaces features to provide the isolation that is required to run a container